# Unedited files not showing up in repository?

Tags: github, repository

Very new to Github and I downloaded the desktop application in hopes of understanding it better. What I'm trying to do is commit/push files by dragging them into my repository folder, but they don't show in application when moved? I tried editing a txt file and as soon as I save it, it appears. I don't want to have to edit every file I add to my repository as I edit it elsewhere. How do I make the non-edited, dragged-and-dropped files appear?

Also, is there an official GitHub support forum? I can't find anything on their website where you can ask questions/etc and I'm not sure StackOverflow is the best place for this question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's the way how git works. It doesn't make sense to add every time the unedited files.

When it notices you added/edited/removed files, `git` will know that.

I pasted a file (`blocks.gif`) in my repository and in GitHub Desktop it I see the following (click the *1 uncommitted change*) and you should see the new files there. Then you can write a commit message and commit the changes.

> [image]
>
> Also, is there an official GitHub support forum?

When you need help using GitHub, you can always [contact the support team](https://github.com/contact) (or write an email to `support@github.com`). They are awesome people. `:)`

https://github.com/contact

Comment: `When it notices you added/edited/removed files, git will know that.` I added them by dragging and dropping, but git doesn't know that, apparently. Should I just move my Visual Studio project folders to the GitHub folder with all my repositories? I'm trying to do whatever is most practical.

Comment: @kill4silence Where did you drag-drop the files? Of course, you should add them in the repository directory.

Comment: I drop them into my local repository, which is now at `/Me/Documents/GitHub/Local Repository/`. Dragging files into this folder does not update in the GitHub application. When I edit an existing file there, however, it shows the file and that it's edited.

Comment: @kill4silence That's strange. I couldn't reproduce the issue you're describing. When I paste files in the repository (using the file explorer), they are showing in the GitHub Desktop app. I would suggest contacting GitHub–they will surely help you. :)

Comment: Is there a setting in GitHub that's maybe preventing added files from showing? I tried copying and pasting files in the repository, but those changes weren't picked up either. Or maybe there's a button somewhere that allows you to pick local files and copy them to the repository?

Comment: @kill4silence You have to go to *1 uncommitted changes* and see there the files. Make sure your files are **inside** of the repository folder. See the edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91315/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-kill4silence).